# How to find when "Find My" location tracking was enabled for a contact

Tags: iphone, find-my-friends

I noticed that "Find My" location tracking on my phone was enabled for one of the contacts. Is there a way to find when this was turned on for that contact?

Answer (score 1):

You will see a notification* in your messages with that contact stating "You started sharing location with..."

*This is not a message/text, it's a notification. I believe you can't do a text search for this through Messages app on Mac, unlike the usual text messages.